# printing the item, cost, and quantity using joptionpane

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class market {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int MenuList;  
    String myOrder = "No order currently set"; 
do{  
    System.out.println("---MENU---");
    String[] menu = {"[1]item list","[2]sales","[3]print","[4]exit"};
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        System.out.println(menu[i]);
    }


    String MenuString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Choose number: ");
    MenuList = Integer.parseInt(MenuString);


    if(MenuList==1) { 
        System.out.println();
        String[] list = {"hotdog","donut","eggpie","pizza","lasagna"};
        int[] cost = {5,15,25,35,45};
        int[] price = {10,20,30,40,50};
        int[] qty ={5,5,5,5,5};
        System.out.println("item"+"\tcost"+"\tprice"+"\tinv qty");
        for (int m=0; m<list.length;m++) {
            System.out.println(list[m]+"\t"+cost[m]+"\t\t"+price[m]+"\t\t"+qty[m]);
        }

        myOrder = "";
        ArrayList<String> Orders = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
            String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Select an Item", "Welcome " +  "!",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, list, "Hotdog");

                int itemQty = 0;
                String itemq = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input Quantity");
                itemQty = Integer.parseInt(itemq);
                if(itemQty<1 ||itemQty>5){ 
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid!");
                itemq = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input Quantity");
                }



            Orders.add("Item " + input + "  Quantity " + itemq);
        }

        for(String s : Orders){
            myOrder += "\n" + s; 
        }
     } else if(MenuList==2) {            
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"sales \n" + myOrder);   
    } else if(MenuList==3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,myOrder);
    } else if(MenuList==4) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exit,Bye");
    } else {
        System.out.print("Invalid");
    }
            }while(MenuList != 4); 
}
}
```

no errors here. my problem is i want to print the item and the quantity with its price but i don't know where to put the price and where to start. the output should be 
**item price quantity subtotal(price*quantity)**

```
                    int itemQty = 0;
                    String itemq = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input Quantity");
                    itemQty = Integer.parseInt(itemq);
                    int pricer = price[i];
                    if(itemQty<1 ||itemQty>5){ 
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid!");
                    itemq = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input Quantity");
                    }

                    int subtotal = 0;
                    subtotal = itemQty*pricer;
                Orders.add("Item " + input + "  Quantity " + itemQty + " Price "+ pricer + "subtotal" +subtotal);
            }
```

how do i get the total of all the price ?

done.

so i tried the program and i saw a miscalculation. i inputted hotdog for 5 times and qty is only 1 . it keeps multiplying. what do i do?

Comment: your current code does not have selling array initialized

Comment: opps sorry i just change the int[] selling to int[] price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This and let me know

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NewClass1 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int MenuList;  
    String myOrder = "No order currently set"; 
do{  
    System.out.println("---MENU---");
    String[] menu = {"[1]item list","[2]sales","[3]print","[4]exit"};
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        System.out.println(menu[i]);
    }


    String MenuString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Choose number: ");
    MenuList = Integer.parseInt(MenuString);


    if(MenuList==1) { 
        System.out.println();
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("hotdog", 5);
        map.put("donut", 15);
        map.put("eggpie", 25);
        map.put("pizza", 35);
        map.put("lasagna", 45);

        String[] list = {"hotdog","donut","eggpie","pizza","lasagna"};
        int[] cost = {5,15,25,35,45};
        int[] price = {10,20,30,40,50};
        int[] qty ={5,5,5,5,5};
        System.out.println("item"+"\tcost"+"\tSelling"+"\tinv qty");
        for (int m=0; m<list.length;m++) {
            System.out.println(list[m]+"\t"+cost[m]+"\t\t"+price[m]+"\t\t"+qty[m]);
        }

        myOrder = "";
        ArrayList<String> Orders = new ArrayList<String>();
        int totalbillamount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
            String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Select an Item", "Welcome " +  "!",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, list, "Hotdog");

                int itemQty = 0;
                String itemq = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input Quantity");
                itemQty = Integer.parseInt(itemq);

                if(itemQty<1 ||itemQty>5){ 
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid!");
                itemq = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input Quantity");
                }

            int subtotal = 0;
            subtotal = itemQty * Integer.parseInt(map.get(input).toString());
            totalbillamount += subtotal;
            Orders.add("Item " + input + "  Quantity " + itemq + " Price "+subtotal);
        }
        Orders.add("Total Bill Amount of your order is "+totalbillamount);

        for(String s : Orders){
            myOrder += "\n" + s; 
        }
     } else if(MenuList==2) {            
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"sales \n" + myOrder);   
    } else if(MenuList==3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,myOrder);
    } else if(MenuList==4) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exit,Bye");
    } else {
        System.out.print("Invalid");
    }
            }while(MenuList != 4); 
}
}
```

Comment: i have a new problem regarding this program also. i need to get the total price for all the items

Comment: tell me what is that?

Comment: i have putted it on my post

Comment: check my answered program again

Comment: i choose  hotdog 5times and choose 1 five times the subtotal keeps adding 10 on the output

Comment: again check my whole program and try to make understand your sellf

Comment: any other way of doing this? i dont know the usage of the 2 imports :(
this is what it said in my jcreator Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.